# Kafka consumer group coordinator inconsistent

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a consumer group in kafka. But its state information is inconsistent between mutliple broker. How can this happen? how can we mitigate this once it has happened?

```
bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh  --bootstrap-server 10.32.218.112:9092 --describe --state  --group consumer-group
COORDINATOR (ID)          ASSIGNMENT-STRATEGY       STATE                #MEMBERS
10.32.218.112:9092 (1)    range                     Stable               1


bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh  --bootstrap-server 10.32.67.102:9092 --describe --state  --group consumer-group
COORDINATOR (ID)          ASSIGNMENT-STRATEGY       STATE                #MEMBERS
10.32.218.112:9092 (1)    range                     Stable               1


bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh  --bootstrap-server 10.33.150.9:9092 --describe --state  --group consumer-group
Consumer group 'consumer-group' has no active members.
COORDINATOR (ID)          ASSIGNMENT-STRATEGY       STATE                #MEMBERS
10.35.168.252:9092 (4)                              Empty                0


bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh  --bootstrap-server 10.35.168.252:9092 --describe --state  --group consumer-group
Consumer group 'consumer-group' has no active members.
COORDINATOR (ID)          ASSIGNMENT-STRATEGY       STATE                #MEMBERS
10.35.168.252:9092 (4)                              Empty                0

bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh  --bootstrap-server 10.33.21.48:9092 --describe --state  --group consumer-group
Consumer group 'consumer-group' has no active members.
COORDINATOR (ID)          ASSIGNMENT-STRATEGY       STATE                #MEMBERS
10.35.168.252:9092 (4)                              Empty                0
```

If you can see first 2 brokers believe that broker 1 is coordinator but last 3 believe that another broker is coordinator.
Kafka version 2.0.0.

**UPDATE**

On the same cluster i can see one consumer having 2 coordinator. It could be a cluster level issue. But i am not sure how to go about debugging this.

```
bash kafka-consumer-groups.sh  --bootstrap-server 10.35.168.252:9092 --describe   --group consumer-group-1   --state

COORDINATOR (ID)          ASSIGNMENT-STRATEGY       STATE                #MEMBERS
10.35.168.252:9092 (4)    range                     Stable               34
bash kafka-consumer-groups.sh  --bootstrap-server 10.32.218.112:9092 --describe   --group consumer-group-1   --state

COORDINATOR (ID)          ASSIGNMENT-STRATEGY       STATE                #MEMBERS
10.32.218.112:9092 (1)    range                     Stable               14
```

**UPDATE**

I am able to reproduce the same issue right now by doing these steps for a new consumer group
a. start kafka consumer with group cg1 using brokerip 10.32.218.112:9092

b. validate that status using brokerip 10.32.218.112:9092 is showing consumer as live

c. validate that status using brokerip 10.35.168.252:9092 is showing consumer not live

d. start kafka consumer with group cg1 using brokerip 10.35.168.252:9092

e. validate that status using brokerip 10.32.218.112:9092 is showing consumer as live

f. validate that status using brokerip 10.35.168.252:9092 is showing consumer as live

but the consumer id both the brokers are reporting are different. Also when we stop both the consumers last read commit offset reported by both the brokers are different.
Confirming that both the consumers are treated separately.

Comment: Are you sure these brokers are all in the same Kafka cluster? Or do you have an even number of Zookeepers running? More specifically, bootstrapping finds all brokers in one cluster. If you get different answers, then it's bootstrapping differently

Comment: but since kafka 2.0.0, the owner coordinator information is not kept in zookeeper right? And yes i am sure that it is same cluster.

Comment: we have 5 zookeeper instances running. but even number of brokers are there (6)

Comment: Zookeeper still controls leader election of the controller, even if it doesn't track it (which I think it does via the broker ids)

Comment: i have validated that there is only 1 controller in the cluster.

Comment: Can you install `kcat` show output from `kcat -L -b` command between each bootstrap server?

Comment: I checked ```kcat -L -b``` on all the boxes. The information on all the broker is the same. For some reason ordering of information on broker 1,2 is different from ordering of broker 3,4,5,6. (since these 2 are actually making mini clusters does that give any sort of pointer?)

Comment: debugging further i am seeing same consumer group being assigned to different partition of __consumer_offsets (and hence different coordinator), hence it clearly does not seem like cluster config issue. Debuging further in kafka code to see how this assignment happens (based on what i had read, the assignment is consumergroupname.hashCode()%number of partition, but this should not change over time.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the "mini cluster" response. All listeners should be the same, but output ordering shouldn't matter. Consumers only produce into the offsets topic, using default partitioner, yes, not get "assigned" any partition, and have no relationship with coordinators

Comment: @OneCricketeer i have found the issue, please review the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First let's understand how consumer group describe command works.

1. when we run the command with n number of broker ips, the call is sent to 1 broker randomly (Let's say A).
2. The broker chooses another broker which it believes is least loaded (Let's say B) and fires a FIND_COORDINATOR request.
3. The coordinator for consumer group (let's say consumerGroupName) is the broker, which is partition leader of __consumer_offset topic's partitionid = "consumerGroupName".hashCode() % (number of partitions in __consumer_offset topic)

   For example lets say there are 50 partitions in __consumer_offset topic. The coordinator for consumer group "test-consumer-group" will be the broker who is leader for partition  "test-consumer-group".hashCode()%50

   The number of partitions are loaded on [kafka startup time](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/3.3.1/core/src/main/scala/kafka/coordinator/group/GroupMetadataManager.scala#L176). We should refrain from changing number of partition for __consumer_offset topic.
4. Now that broker A knows the coordinator broker, it will send request to the coordinator for the latest offset details. The consumer detail may not be present if

   a. the consumer was never live

   b. the ttl for __consumer_offset is less than the last active time for consumer group.

   c. the replication factor for __consumer_offset is 1 and there was data loss for the particular partition.

In our case we had increased the number of partition for __consumer_offset topic (which is [very wrong thing to do](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-10182) as it will render all the consumer group hashes inconsistent.) but also did not restart all the brokers. So some brokers in the cluster assumed x partitions to be there while others assumed it to be y as prior to 2.8.2 version, this information is not updated, unless we restart kafka broker. Because of this, at times some brokers were chosen as coordinator but they were not aware of the consumer group, hence we were getting inconsistent responses.

Comment: Hey @best-wishes 
Even in the latest version (3.3.1), the number of partitions for consumer offset topic is [loaded only at startup](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/3.3.1/core/src/main/scala/kafka/coordinator/group/GroupMetadataManager.scala#L176). Could you please help me understand what change in 2.8.2 would refresh the number of partitions of this topic periodically?

Comment: Thanks @Divij for pointing out. Updating the answer.  I might have overlooked this.